# materialize css btn class doesnt apply custom font

Tags: css, fonts, materialize

I'm working on an online store project and it needs a custom font. I'm using Materialize CSS framework in Angular 7, but btn class doesn't apply correctly custom font, anything else does. any help please friends!

I have tried custom btn class apply to style with !important, it does apply but damaged ways.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'AcadNusx';
  src: url('./assets/fonts/AcadNusx.woff') format('woff2'),
      url('./assets/fonts/AcadNusx.woff2') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
    font-family: 'AcadNusx' !important;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

a {
    font-family: 'AcadNusx' !important;
  }

.btn {
  font-family: 'AcadNusx' !important;
}
```

and the template code is: 
 registracia
when I delete btn class from the button font apply correctly but there is no styling
please help, I need just to apply this font but btn style is making me headache. thanks for your attention.
best regards

Answer (score 0):

AcadNusx is an 'unusual' Georgian typeset _
To display it correctly needs more @font-face information than you currently have in your CSS code _

According to the Fonts2U resource_ you need to upload (or install via Angular cli?) all 4 versions of the font to your fonts folder_ including .ttf,.woff,.eot,.svg  _ then copy / paste the accompanying CSS code into your main CSS file or import the code as separate CSS _

The 4 versions of the font_ the CSS code_ and all the instructions you need_ are all included in the downloadable resource from: https://fonts2u.com/acadnusx.font